# How do I get my xclock to display in my ubuntu? Can't seem to fix this error

Tags: server, display, users, error-handling, clock

I'm trying to get my xclock to show in my ubuntu, I get this error when I try to get xclock to show:

```
chopin:~% xclock &
[1] 7888
chopin:~% Error: Can't open display: 

[1]    Exit 1                        xclock
chopin:~%
```

Do I need to install some new things to my ubuntu?

Comment: You tagged this `server`, and the `DISPLAY` variable appears to be unset: are you actually running an X session or just a CLI?

Comment: sorry I'm running my ubuntu on my windows, really stuck right now! If you have time, you mind email me, gethbonow at gmail. It's a temporary account I've created, so your privacy will be safe! please consider

Comment: How are you running Ubuntu on Windows ? Bash on windows ? A virtual machine ? Are you running a graphical display on the server ? If you are running bash on windows, graphical apps are not full supported, see https://www.howtogeek.com/261575/how-to-run-graphical-linux-desktop-applications-from-windows-10s-bash-shell/ for how to install and use a X display in windows, XMing in this case. You can also install an X server through Cygwin